# Are i/o device polling intervals often consistent?

Tags: operating-system, kernel

this is a quick question about common existing operating systems.

Is a polled io device (say of 120hz or 250hz) generally getting polled at a fixed rate or there are usually considerable fluctuations in polling intervals, and if there are fluctuations, are they in terms of milliseconds or micro/nanoseconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends upon the processor architecture, system and application design.  Your basic reference is [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science)#Algorithm).

In an embedded system where the result and latency of polling a particular device may be the most important and central purpose of the system, you are likely to see a tight loop busy-waiting at processor instruction speeds (micro/nanoseconds) with low jitter.  These intervals may not be completely deterministic due to modern processor architecture improvements such as speculative branching depending on the surrounding code; see [this relevant StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189662/intel-serializing-instructions-and-branch-prediction?rq=1).

In a multitasking system doing lots of things and occasionally polling for, say, keystrokes from a [HID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_interface_device) of course there will be considerably higher latency in units more like milliseconds.  Tasks may switch, processes may be swapped in and out etc.

This is a quick answer to your quick question - trying to put you into the ballpark but making clear that there could be a lot at play here depending on your environment.

Comment: Such a nice fast answer, I really liked it, have a good day/rest of day.